# Determining Firewall settings (Ports, etc) for specific applications

Tags: network, firewalls, ports

How can we identify the network or network firewall requirements for a Desktop or Web application. Meaning what ports are required by the applications.
How the Cloud and non Cloud networks communicate with each other.
Are there specific settings required? If both network are in different domain?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows or *nix you can use `netstat`.  On Windows, you do a `nestat | find "LISTEN"`, and on Linux use `netstat -nl`, but on *BSD use `netstat -na | grep -i listen`.  This tells you what services are in a listening state.

Once you know what ports a service is listening on, you can adjust the appropriate rule(s).

Comment: Thanks !! apart from this commands, are there any tools available which can help to identify these? Also please let me know How the Cloud and non Cloud network communicate each other. Is there any specific setting required? if both network are in different domain?

Comment: um, this is a terribly open-ended series of questions.  Short of a packet capture, the most certain way to ascertain which ports are used in various communications -- whether they are cloud-based or not -- is a function of analyzing the traffic.  If a packet capture is outside your current skill-set, I suggest you read-up on wireshark.  Its a glorious tool.

Answer (score 1):

The other way to look at it is from the firewall end and monitor the traffic from the host as it hits the firewall. This is a good way, as it allows you to see anything getting blocked and the firewall already has to deencapsulate the traffic.

Eithter that or back to the manual method, most apps that use communictations publish this data in the manual or on the web. if its not published, you can usually get the info from the support team.